# Bot Framework: Why can't I use SendAsync?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I've been following [this VSTF_RD_Bot example code](https://github.com/jeffhollan/BotFrameworkSample/blob/master/Bot/VSTF_RD_Bot/Controllers/MessagesController.cs).

I'm unable to build this code because I get the following message:

> The type arguments for method '`Conversation.SendAsync<T>(Message,
>   Func<IDialog<T>>, CancellationToken)`' cannot be inferred from the
>   usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

What does this mean and how can I fix it? I tried numerous times to reinstall all the Microsoft.Bot.Builder packages but to no avail. I don't know how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does this mean

It means what it says. You call with a parameter that needs to be specified (generic function) but the type can not be automatically inferred, so you msut specify it EXPLICITLY.

It even tells you that:

> Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
>
> and how can I fix it? I tried numerous times to reinstall all the
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder packages but to no avail.

Read up Einstein on repeatedly trying things that fail - his comment is spot on and not friendly. Computers do not work by random compilation. Fails one, reinstall will not fix it.

If that is sample code, it is broken - for whatever reason (using the wrong compiler version?). You should do what any programmer does in this case and fix the error, as per error message.

> ```
> Conversation.SendAsync<T>(Message, Func<IDialog<T>>, CancellationToken)
> ```

Specify `T` explicitly in the call. I can only assume (you do not bother to provide the failing code line - shame on you) that the call is in the form `variable.SendAsync(` which means the compiler would have to guess `T` - but it fails there. Specify `T` explicitly and this error goes away.

Comment: When I add the <T> on line 77 a red line appears underneath VSTFDialog  `var reply = await Conversation.SendAsync<T>(message, () => new VSTFDialog());`

Comment: You should not add T - you should SPECIFY T, replacing the type placeholder T with a sensible parameter. You should also read up on the method - ittakes a FUNC<IDialog<T>> but you specifiy () - with no parameter. Maybe it is time to learn some basic C#? Generics, generic parameters, open and closed types and methods? Because if you do not know C# this is way too broad.

Comment: yes, is there a good readup for Java developers? I think this may be some dependency related issue with nuget packages

Comment: @TomTom `Func<IDialog<T>>` [declares the `TResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it does not accept parameters, so the `() => new VSTFDialog()` is correct.